# How can i filter JSON file with nearest object key using JQ?

Tags: jq

I have to filter JSON file with nearest object name using JQ.

I already try with command:

```
jq '.data[] |select(.orderid=="40007600")' output.json
```

but the command only filter the object with exact name. I want to filter the object start with string "40007" like that : `.orderid="40007"`.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "orderid": "40007600",
      "price": "9.99",
      "listingname": "iPhone 8",
      "smallphoto": "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51b5iaLTjgL._SL160_.jpg",
      "photo": "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51b5iaLTjgL.jpg"
    },
     {
      "orderid": "40007598",
      "price": "9.99",
      "listingname": "iPhone 8 Plus",
      "smallphoto": "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51CVLqsSNkL._SL160_.jpg",
      "photo": "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51CVLqsSNkL.jpg"
    },
     {
      "orderid": "40007595",
      "price": "9.39",
      "listingname": "Nadelflaschen",
      "smallphoto": "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41OHDP2rAeL._SL160_.jpg",
      "photo": "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41OHDP2rAeL.jpg"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "nearest"? Do you mean string that starts with "40007" or string that contains "40007"?

Comment: yes, i mean the string starts with "40007"

Answer (score 1):

```
jq '.data[] | select(.orderid | startswith("40007"))' output.json
```